# How to split on ( not a value ) followed by ( a value )?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code here:

```
var fields = row.split(/regex goes here/);
```

I want to split row on each occurrence of

```
|
```

but not

```
*|
```

How do I write this simple regular expression.  I thought there was a not character of sorts but I can't seem to find a good reference right now.

I know I need to escape the special character `|` like this `\|`..but how do I add the not part?

Likely I will just switch my markup to

```
|*
```

instead of

```
*|
```

and than I can this form I found on MDN - match x only if not followed by y.

```
x(?!y)
```

I'm testing here:

http://www.regexpal.com/

Found a good reference here

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions

Comment: I'm deleting my post because it's not correct. So far I've not been able to find a solution that doesn't truncate the last character of items that don't have the *

Comment: ever heard of rubular.com it's suppsedly ruby specific, but I use it as a base for finding the best base regex I can for a solution. if it's too involved, you're doing too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `split()` on the delimiter. Just `.match()` everything *between* delimiters:

```
var fields = row.match(/(?:\*\||[^|])*/g);
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:    # Match either
 \*\|  # *|
|      # or
 [^|]  # any character except |
)*     # Repeat as needed
```

Comment: The end cases break....I can't find a way to to this using split() or match() so far

Answer (score 1):

What you need is lookbehind which is not supported by JavaScript.

> Finally, flavors like JavaScript, Ruby and Tcl do not support
>   lookbehind at all, even though they do support lookahead.
>   — http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

You need to do some kind of hack. Replace all your `*|` with some kind of unique character sequence. Then split on `|`, and finally replace those special character sequences back into `*|`.

As a side note. If you are creating some kind of wiki engine, you may try to find [one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software#JavaScript-based) that is ready made.

Comment: Bingo. No lookbehinds; use sentries.

Comment: @GuyMontag The character sequence that you temporarily replace `*|` with would be called a sentry (or sentinel).

Comment: @GGG: No need to use sentries if you don't have to use `.split()`. See my solution.

Comment: @TimPietzcker nice approach, removes the need for `split` altogether.

Comment: @Tim...I can't find a way to get all cases to work so far...sentries might be my best bet....this is the failing case....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777817/how-to-properly-escape-split-and-unescape-data